How to implement lazy loading in kendo treeview structure?
 var jsonDataParent = @Html.Raw(Model.TrailerModelTreeViewModel.JsonTreeDataBrand);
 var jsonDataChild =  @Html.Raw(Model.TrailerModelTreeViewModel.JsonTreeDataModel);
 var kendoTreeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
 data: [
     jsonDataParent 
 ],
 schema: {
     model: {
         children: "subCategories",
         hasChildren: "hasChildren"
     }
 }
});
function treeDataBound() {
 var selectedValues = '@Model.SearchFilterViewModel.SelectedItems';
 if (selectedValues != "")
 {
     var selectedNodes = selectedValues.split(",");
     if (selectedNodes.length > 0) {
         $("#treeview input[type=checkbox]").each(function (e) {
             var checkboxId = $(this).attr("value");

             if (selectedNodes.indexOf(checkboxId.toString()) > -1) {
                 if ($(this).is(":checked") == false) {
                     $(this).click();
                     setTimeout(function () {
                         onCheck();
                     }, 1);
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 }
}
var fillSubItems = function (dataItem) {
 var items = [];
 var subCat = jsonDataChild.subCategories;
 for (i = 0; i < subCat.length; i++)
 {
     if (dataItem.id.split('-')[0] == subCat[i][0].treeNodeId) {
             items.push(subCat[i])
     }
 }
 return items
}
 $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
 checkboxes: {
     template: "<input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='#= 
 item.id #' aria-label='#= item.id #'/>",
     checkChildren: true
 },
 dataBound:treeDataBound,
 dataSource: kendoTreeData,
 loadOnDemand: true,
 dataTextField: ["categoryName", "subCategoryName"],
 expand: function (e)
 {
     var item = treeview.dataItem(e.node);
     setTimeout(function () {
     var subitems = fillSubItems(item);
     treeview.children.data(subitems);
     }, 500);
   }
});
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
$($("#treeview input[type=checkbox]").first()[0]).hide();
setTimeout(function () {
 $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').collapse("ul li :not(:eq(0))");
}, 1);
treeview.dataSource.bind("change", function (event) {
 runAlready = false;
 if (event.field == "checked")
     onCheck();
 });

I need to implement lazy loading in Kendo TreeView because of the large volume of data. The parent and child nodes are stored separately in two different JSON objects. However, currently, only the parent node checkboxes are appearing, and the expand icon for child nodes is not visible. Could someone help identify any issues in this code?
JSON format:-
{
"categoryName": "Brand Model",
"treeNodeId": "0-0",
"subCategories": [
  {
    "subCategoryName": "Brand1",
    "treeNodeId": "",
    "id": "1996-0",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryName": "UNKNOWN",
        "treeNodeId": "1996",
        "id": "2812-1996",
        "subCategories": "",
        "expanded": true,
        "checked": false,
        "HasChildren": false 
      }
    ],
     "expanded": true,
     "checked": false,
     "HasChildren": true
   },
   {
     "subCategoryName": "Brand2",
     "treeNodeId": "",
     "id": "1208-0",
     "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryName": "UNKNOWN",
        "treeNodeId": "1208",
        "id": "2232-1208",
        "subCategories": "",
        "expanded": true,
        "checked": false,
        "HasChildren": false
      }
    ],
    "expanded": true,
    "checked": false,
    "HasChildren": true
   }
 ]
}

Json Model:-
jsonModel.Add(new
{
   subCategoryName = Model.Brand,
   treeNodeId = string.Empty,
   id = Model.MakeSK + "-0",
   subCategories = subCat,
   expanded = true,
   @checked = isChecked,
   HasChildren = true
 });

subCategories (child nodes data) is empty for parent Json object.

I see you pass the parent and child data via the model, so I would suggest considering a slightly different approach - build the parent/child data relation on the server instead, pass the data structure to the treeview and let it handle the rest of the operations. The loadOnDemand option would do just that - render only the items for the current level, but not all items. If you uncomment the loadOnDemand in this example and inspect the markup you will note the leaf for Brand1 is not rendered until you expand the Brand1 node.
If the expand/collapse icons are not showing pay attention to the fields mapping - in the dataSource definition you have hasChildren: "hasChildren" while the JSON format shared the field is in PascalCase: "HasChildren". Also consider using a different field name for the id - it seems id is used internally by the treeview, so the field you have in the JSON format will not be mapped, hence the update to nid in the example.
